# Jquery tab spinner does not stop in IE

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have added spinner for jquery tab widget. It works fine on firefox, chrome and safari.

Only in IE when I click on the tab spinner starts and continues to spin even when data is loaded.

```
$("#mainTabContainer").tabs({ selected: tabIndex, 
                              spinner: spinnerImage, 
                              cache: true, 
                              select: fixTabAbort});
```

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We did following to solve this issue:

```
 cj("#elementId").tabs( {
   ......
   ......
   ......
   load: function(event, ui) {
     stopSpinner( );
   }
 });


function stopSpinner( ) {
   $('li.crm-tab-button').each(function(){ $(this).find('span').text(' ');})     
}
```

Hope this helps